# Разбор по составу слова "ассоциация"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Помогите разобрать слово "ассоциация" по составу. Как в общем случае делать разбор заимствованных слов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ассоци/аци/я

Разбор делается всё так же: отсекается окончание -ассоциаци/я, ассоциаци/и,ассоциаци/ю,  ассоциаци/ей,

затем суффикс- ассоци/(аци/я), ассоци/(ирова/ть), ассоци/(ативн/ый),

остаётся корень-ассоци

Comment: слово иностранное  от лат. associare — соединять.
socia, ae f [socius] подруга или спутница (vitae s. 
virtus С); (тж. s. tori О) супруга SI. 
от этого корня socium
наши правила словообразования непригодны. Корень другой.

Comment: @petro, если слово уже перекочевало в русский язык, то его можно разобрать, ведь для него есть примеры словоизменения и словообразования. В любом случае хочется услышать ваш вариант.

Comment: ответ кроется в слове русском, созвучном латинскому, сами дальше думайте.

Answer (score 0):

Петро, слово утратило свое историческое значение, а следовательно, на современном этапе языка выделяются те морфемы, которые привела Людмила.

Comment: И якобы теряются корни исходного языка, не так ли? Или вы их собственным незнанием иностранных языков просто губите? А потом ваш разбор выдаете за науку побеждать чужие мнения? Не так ли? Думается, что если копнуть поглубже от "исторического значения", вы рожки с ножками оставите и перейдете на ЭСПЕРАНТО.

Comment: Не обижайте эсперанто, уважаемый. Я его в детстве изучал и потом переписывался с эсперантистами многих стран.

Comment: Уважаемый Петро! Это вы пытаетесь навязать свое мнение, которое не соответствует современным правилам. Если вы решились искать глубокие корни, ищите ох в индоевропейском языке.  Потому что латинский восходит к индоевропейскому языку.

Comment: Уважаемый Серж, сдается по всему, что  индоевропейский выдумали, потому как такового не было и нет. Никто на нем не разговаривал и не писал. Слова со звездочкой плод фантазии, это тоже без вариантов,вместе с классификаций. То, что вы ей поклоняетесь, не повод поклоняться остальным. У нас свобода вероисповедания. Я вам его не навязываю, детские пристрастия не осуждаю. Ищу корни в тех языках, которые не выдумывали.